# jQuery hide or show element depending on other element's class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to hide/show an element depending on the class of a specific element in the page (the class changes whether the element is selected or not). How could I do that with jQuery? I thought about using the click() or change() function and then check the element's class to hide() or show() the other element.

I try with the following code but it does not work:

```html
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
    disableSectorAnalysis();
});
        
function disableSectorAnalysis(){        
    jQuery('#ygvtableel66').click(function(){
    if (jQuery('#ygvtableel66').attr("class") == "ygtvtable ygtvdepth2 ygtv-highlight0") {
        jQuery('select[id*="SectorGliederung"]').hide();
    } else jQuery('select[id*="SectorGliederung"]').show();       
    });
 }    
</script>
```

The html code is the following. A 3-level tree is generated with Primefaces 2.2.1 library and I would like to hide/show the "Sectorgliederung element" when a specific node is unchecked/checked. 
But in Primefaces 2.2.1 there does not seem to be a method to trigger an event on a specific node selection, which is why I am trying to access the value of each node through jQuery.

```html
<div class="punktlinie958"></div>
<h2>Fondsmodulauswahl</h2>

<table class="Formular" width="944px">
<tr>
<th>Fondsmodule<br/>inkl. Zusatzmodule</th>
<td>
<p:tree value="#{treeFonds.root}" 
  var="node3" 
  selectionMode="checkbox"
  selection="#{treeFonds.selectedNodes}"
  
  propagateSelectionDown="true"
  propagateSelectionUp="true"
  
  expandAnim="FADE_IN"
  collapseAnim="FADE_OUT">

 <p:treeNode>
  <h:outputText value="#{node3}"/>
  
 </p:treeNode>
 <p:treeNode type="nodesFondsAnalyseKlein" >
  <h:outputText value="#{node3}"/>
 
 </p:treeNode>
 <p:treeNode type="nodesPerformanceNetto">
  <h:outputText value="#{node3}"/>
 
 </p:treeNode>
 <p:treeNode type="nodesPerformanceBrutto">
  <h:outputText value="#{node3}"/>
  
 </p:treeNode>
 <p:treeNode type="nodesFondsAnalyseMittel">
  <h:outputText value="#{node3}"/>
  
 </p:treeNode>
 <p:treeNode type="nodesFondsAnalyseGroß">
  <h:outputText value="#{node3}"/>
  
 </p:treeNode>
 <p:treeNode type="nodesZusatzFonds">
  <h:outputText value="#{node3}"/>
  
 </p:treeNode> 
</p:tree> 
</td>
</tr>



<tr>
<th>Aktienanalyse<br/>nach Sektoren **</th>
<td>
<h:selectOneMenu id="SectorGliederung"
 value="#{fondsBean.fonds2mappe.sectorgliederung.id}"
 disabled="#{sitzungBean.prio1Disabled}" styleClass="gross"
 style="float:left">
 <f:selectItems value="#{fondsBean.sectorgliederung}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
</td>
</tr>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please create a proper [mcve].

Comment: Why dont you hide/ show that element whenever you trigger the action that changes the class?

Comment: can you please elaborate more on your problem. What other class you are talking about? can you add relevant html code in the post?

Comment: You are not selecting the element by class, but by id. Change `'#element'` to `'.element'` will select the element by class.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answers, I updated the post.

Comment: Hello all, a quick update on my issue: I finally managed to achieve what I wanted by implementing a click() function for each tree node identified by its css id, checking whether it is clicked or not by looking at its class. Thanks a lot for all your answers and your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use code like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
  hideElement();
});
        
function hideElement(){
  $(document).on('change', '.changingelement', function(){
    if($(this).val() === "on"){
      $('#element').hide();
    } else {
      $('#element').show();
    }    
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="changingelement" value="on" class="changingelement">On <br/>
<input type="radio" name="changingelement" value="off" class="changingelement">Off

<div id="element">This is toggle div</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but neither the .change() function nor the .click() function seem to work with an element generated within a primefaces tree.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this sample code will help you out:

```js
var divList = $(".parent div");
divList.each(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $(this).addClass("color");//I have changed the color
    /*
     *You can hide/show or do any other function here.
     */
  }
});
```

```css
.color {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div>Inactive</div>
  <div>Inactive</div>
  <div class="active">This is the only active element.</div>
  <div>Inactive</div>
  <div>Inactive</div>
  <div>Inactive</div>
</div>
```

In the above example, `active` class has to be added when you are selecting the element. This class can come handy while performing other functions, that might be specific to the selected elements only. [Can be added on any of the events like `change`, `click`, `blur`, `focus` etc.]

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/qzmb302y/1/) is the reference fiddle for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me. see this

http://jsfiddle.net/DfPbJ/1/

your HTML

```
<div class="statecontent state1">State1 Specific Page Content Goes here</div><br />
<div class="statecontent state1">State1 Specific Page2 Content Goes here</div><br />
<div class="statecontent state2">State2 Specific Page Content Goes here</div><br />
<div class="statecontent state3">State3 Specific Page Content Goes here</div><br />

<select id="myselector">
<option value="state1"></option><br />
<option value="state2"></option><br />
<option value="state3"></option><br />
</select>
```

your JQuery

```
$('.statecontent').hide();
$('#myselector').change(function() {
$('.statecontent').hide();
$('.' + $(this).val()).show();    
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but neither the .change() function nor the .click() function seem to work with an element generated within a primefaces tree.

Answer (score 0):

your html like

```
<div id="changingelement" class="test"></div>

<div id="test"> test class details </div>

<span id="notTest"> Hello </span>
```

And your script will be,

```
if($('#changingelement').hasClass("notTest"))
{
  $('#test').hide();
} 
else($('#changingelement').hasClass("test"))
{
  $("#notTest").hide();
}
```